# how to link Spring boot Rest API unit test, integration test, owasp dependency check coverage to sonarqube

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a new springboot rest api  and i want unit test coverage of the api, integration test to reflect in sonarqube. I created a project from spring initalizer. How to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

1. First in your springboot pom file add jacoco plugin to generate unit test reports

```
 <properties>
     <java.version>11</java.version>
     <spring-boot.version>2.5.6</spring-boot.version>
  <dependency-check-maven.version>7.1.0</dependency-check-maven.version>
<jacoco-maven-plugin>0.8.7</jacoco-maven-plugin>
       <sonar.exclusions>
         **/*Application.*,
         **/config/*.java,
         **/model/*,
         **/*exception/*,
         **/*Test.*,**/*IT.*
     </sonar.exclusions>
     <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
     <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
     <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>

<!-- from difference source
<coverage.exclusions.default>src/test/**,**/*Application.*,**/BackendApplication.java</coverage.exclusions.default>
     <!-- Start with a ',' in case of overriding the empty additional coverage exclusions -->
<coverage.exclusions.additional>**/config/*.java</coverage.exclusions.additional>
     <sonar.sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sonar.sourceEncoding>
     <sonar.junit.reportPaths>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>
     <sonar.coverage.exclusions>${coverage.exclusions.default}${coverage.exclusions.additional}</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
     <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
     <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
     <sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>target/dependency-check-report.json</sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>
     <sonar.dependencyCheck.securityHotspot>true</sonar.dependencyCheck.securityHotspot>
-->
     
 </properties>
 <build>
    <plugin>
             <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
             <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                 <excludes>
                     <exclude>**/*Application.*</exclude>
                     <exclude>**/config/*</exclude>
                     <exclude>**/model/*</exclude>
                     <exclude>**/*exception/*</exclude>
//for generated pojos from wsdl file nl.soapservice.somepackage.abc.pojo.java or nl.soapservice.somepackage.pojo.java
                 <exclude>nl/soapservice/somepackage/**/*</exclude>
                     <exclude>nl/soapservice/somepackage/**</exclude>
               
                 </excludes>
             </configuration>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>report</id>
                     <phase>test</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>report</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                     <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>post-integration-test</id>
                     <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>report</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>merge-unit-and-integration</id>
                     <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>merge</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <fileSets>
                             <fileSet>
                                 <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                 <includes>
                                     <include>*.exec</include>
                                 </includes>
                             </fileSet>
                         </fileSets>
                         <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</destFile>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>create-merged-report</id>
                     <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>report</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged.exec</dataFile>
                         <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-merged</outputDirectory>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>

  <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                     <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                     <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
                     <configuration>
                         <formats>
                             <format>html</format>
                             <format>json</format>
                         </formats>
                         <skipProvidedScope>false</skipProvidedScope>
                         <skipRuntimeScope>false</skipRuntimeScope>
                     </configuration>
                     <executions>
                         <execution>
                             <goals>
                                 <goal>check</goal>
                             </goals>
                         </execution>
                     </executions>
                 </plugin>
//generate pojos from wsdl
 <plugin>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
             <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>${jaxb2-maven-plugin.version}</version>
             <dependencies>
                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                     <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                     <version>2.3.3</version>
                 </dependency>
             </dependencies>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>xjc</id>
                     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>xjc</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <sources>
                         
                             <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/Header_10.xsd</source>
                             <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/XMLFault_10.xsd</source>
                             <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ReqPojo_1_REQ.xsd</source>
                             <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/RespPojo_1_RPY.xsd</source>
                         </sources>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
</build>
```

2. Next create a project in sonarqube for your api. And execute the following commands from your project terminal from your computer.

```
mvn sonar:sonar \
-Dsonar.projectKey=project name in sonar \
-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.domain.com \
-Dsonar.login=73ddeb4f164634038ce6c021d33a23d48(token generated in sonar website)
-Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

3. Using the above maven jacoco plugin sonarqube reads the results from target and publishes the results
   [https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/#:~:text=Test%20coverage%20reports%20and%20test,been%20run%20and%20their%20results](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/#:%7E:text=Test%20coverage%20reports%20and%20test,been%20run%20and%20their%20results).